# How to forward data to next page with Apollo and NextJS

Tags: react-hooks, next.js, apollo, apollo-client

I'm working on a web app with NextJS, Apollo and React (hooks).

I have a form that asks the name of the visitor as the first step in a registration process. 
When submitting the form the name will be saved in the Apollo cache and the visitor gets redirected to the next page.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Router , {useRouter}  from 'next/router';
import { useApolloClient } from '@apollo/react-hooks';


const NameForm = props => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const client = useApolloClient();
    const router = useRouter();

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(!name) return;

        client.writeData({ data: { name } });
        router.push('/user/register');
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="name">Naam</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
                    <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Get started</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}

export default NameForm;
```

The next page contains a more extensive form. When visitors come from the homepage, the name is already known and I want to get it back from the cache. I thought

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';
import { useApolloClient } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import AddUserForm from '../../components/forms/AddUserForm';

const GET_NAME = gql` 
 query GetName {
    name @client  
}`;

const AddUser = ({ name }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <AddUserForm name={name} />
    </React.Fragment>
)

AddUser.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
    const client = useApolloClient();
    const name = await client.cache.readQuery({ query: GET_NAME });

    return { name: name || '' };
}

export default AddUser;
```

I thought I could do this in the getInititialProps hooks are only allowed in the body of a functional component.

Because of the continuous development of next, react hooks and apollo I'm missing a tutorial/course about this and I find it difficult to find a right way to do this.

I hope someone here can help me further.

Answer (score 4):

use apollo-client cache can lead you to some questions that really depends on the `apollo-client`'s implementation and `nextjs` implementation.
If you open your app by entering the url to the browser address bar, `Next.js` will make requests (assuming the view need to fetch data) from server-side, then send to the client the rendered HTML.

Because `apollo-client` fetch then cache the data from server side, then the question is **"Does Next.js send the apollo-client with its cache to client side for next request?"**

- You cannot sure about this unless you understand clearly about `Next.js` and `apollo-client cache` (about its implementation or how it works inside, if `apollo` cache data in-memory on server-side, you will fail if you go this way)
- The answer is **unsure** because it depends on two stuffs at the same time. And maybe changed on the future!

So to deal with this problem, just use the `Next.js` way, it has designed a tunnel for data, it is the `query` on the url.

```js
const NameForm = props => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const client = useApolloClient();
    const router = useRouter();

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!name) return;
        router.push(`/user/register?name=${name}`);
    }
    //render ...
}
```

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import AddUserForm from '../../components/forms/AddUserForm';
const AddUser = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <AddUserForm name={router.query.name} />
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
export default AddUser;
```

**If you want to send an object instead of a string?**

```js
const data = { name: "FoxeyeRinx", email: "foxeye.rinx@gmail.com" };
const base64 = btoa(JSON.stringify(data));
router.push(`/user/register?data=${base64}`);
```

```js
const AddUser = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const base64 = router.query.data;
    //decode base64 then parse it to js object
    const data = JSON.parse(atob(base64)); 
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <AddUserForm data={data}/>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

**If you think the query is ugly and want to hide the query**, use this guide: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/clean-urls-with-dynamic-routing